# Find an object in SQL Server (cross-database)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

If I've been told a table (or proc) name, but not which connected database the object is located in, is there any simple script to search for it?  Maybe search somewhere in the System Databases?  (I'm using SQL Server 2005)

Comment: Can't test this on 2005, but this should find the object in any database: https://ghostbin.com/paste/cwyxt

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is a schema called `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema which contains a set of views on tables from the SYS schema that you can query to get what you want.

A major upside of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is that the object names are very query friendly and user readable. The downside of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is that you have to write one query for each type of object.

The Sys schema may seem a little cryptic initially, but it has all the same information (and more) in a single spot.

You'd start with a table called SysObjects (each database has one) that has the names of all objects and their types.

One could search in a database as follows:

```
Select [name] as ObjectName, Type as ObjectType
From Sys.Objects
Where 1=1
    and [Name] like '%YourObjectName%'
```

Now, if you wanted to restrict this to only search for tables and stored procs, you would do

```
Select [name] as ObjectName, Type as ObjectType
From Sys.Objects
Where 1=1
    and [Name] like '%YourObjectName%'
    and Type in ('U', 'P')
```

If you look up object types, you will find a whole list for views, triggers, etc.

Now, if you want to search for this in each database, you will have to iterate through the databases.  You can do one of the following:

If you want to search through each database without any clauses, then use the sp_MSforeachdb as shown in an answer here.

If you only want to search specific databases, use the "USE DBName" and then search command.

You will benefit greatly from having it parameterized in that case. Note that the name of the database you are searching in will have to be replaced in each query (DatabaseOne, DatabaseTwo...). Check this out:

```
Declare @ObjectName VarChar (100)

Set @ObjectName = '%Customer%'

Select 'DatabaseOne' as DatabaseName, [name] as ObjectName, Type as ObjectType
From DatabaseOne.Sys.Objects
Where 1=1
    and [Name] like @ObjectName
    and Type in ('U', 'P')

UNION ALL

Select 'DatabaseTwo' as DatabaseName, [name] as ObjectName, Type as ObjectType
From DatabaseTwo.Sys.Objects
Where 1=1
    and [Name] like @ObjectName
    and Type in ('U', 'P')

UNION ALL

Select 'DatabaseThree' as DatabaseName, [name] as ObjectName, Type as ObjectType
From DatabaseThree.Sys.Objects
Where 1=1
    and [Name] like @ObjectName
    and Type in ('U', 'P')
```

Comment: @itsho, if the universe breaks, Raj More doesn't want to waste time running database queries. :)

Comment: @itsho it's for code readability.  Each AND is on a separate line, and although it's not obvious in the way SO has displayed the code, they would often be indented.  Also, it makes it ever-so-easier to comment out any/all conditions.  Without the 1=1, you can't comment out the first condition without also removing the 'AND' on the next line.   So, it does nothing to affect the query, but makes it easier for the user running the command.

Answer (score 15):

```
sp_MSforeachdb 'select db_name(), * From ?..sysobjects where xtype in (''U'', ''P'') And name = ''ObjectName'''
```

Instead of 'ObjectName' insert object you are looking for. First column will display name of database where object is located at.

Comment: db_name() is the current database, ''?'' will be the database being searched.  So the first column will be the same for all records, if you need to know which database the object is in use: sp_MSforeachdb 'select ''?'', * From ?..sysobjects where xtype in (''U'', ''P'') And name = ''ObjectName'''

Comment: Best answer according to me. However, I'd remove the type filter in the case you don't know the type of the object you're searching.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to hit up the information_schemas...

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.Tables
WHERE [Table_Name]='????'

SELECT *
FROM information_schema.Views
WHERE [Table_Name]='????'

SELECT *
FROM information_schema.Routines
WHERE [Routine_Name]='????'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using the following query:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 
    'IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT  1 
        FROM    [?].sys.objects 
        WHERE   name LIKE ''OBJECT_TO_SEARCH''
    )
    SELECT 
        ''?''       AS DB, 
        name        AS Name, 
        type_desc   AS Type 
    FROM [?].sys.objects 
    WHERE name LIKE ''OBJECT_TO_SEARCH'''
```

Just replace OBJECT_TO_SEARCH with the actual object name you are interested in (or part of it, surrounded with %).

More details here: https://peevsvilen.blog/2019/07/30/search-for-an-object-in-sql-server/

Comment: This should be the answer. For brevity, ingenuity, and making the focus how to get objects for an entire sql server instance (cross database, where the user has permission).

Answer (score 1):

You can use sp_MSforeachdb to search all databases.

declare @RETURN_VALUE int

declare @command1 nvarchar(2000)

set @command1 = "Your command goes here"

exec @RETURN_VALUE = sp_MSforeachdb @command1 = @command1

Raj

Answer (score 1):

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go


/**********************************************************************
Naziv procedure     : sp_rfv_FIND
Ime i prezime autora: Srdjan Nadrljanski
Datum kreiranja     : 13.06.2013. 
Namena              : Traži sql objekat na celom serveru
Tabele              : 
Ulazni parametri    : 
Izlazni parametri   : 
Datum zadnje izmene :  
Opis izmene         : 
exec sp_rfv_FIND 'TUN',''
**********************************************************************/
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_rfv_FIND] (  @SEARCHSTRING VARCHAR(255),
                                        @notcontain Varchar(255)
                                        )
AS


declare @text varchar(1500),@textinit varchar (1500)
set @textinit=
'USE @sifra

insert into ##temp2
select ''@sifra''as dbName,a.[Object Name],a.[Object Type]
from(
 SELECT DISTINCT sysobjects.name AS [Object Name]   ,
case
when sysobjects.xtype = ''C'' then ''CHECK constraint''
when sysobjects.xtype = ''D'' then ''Default or DEFAULT constraint''
when sysobjects.xtype = ''F'' then ''Foreign Key''
when sysobjects.xtype = ''FN'' then ''Scalar function''
when sysobjects.xtype = ''P'' then ''Stored Procedure''
when sysobjects.xtype = ''PK'' then ''PRIMARY KEY constraint''
when sysobjects.xtype = ''S'' then ''System table''
when sysobjects.xtype = ''TF'' then ''Function''
when sysobjects.xtype = ''TR'' then ''Trigger''
when sysobjects.xtype = ''U'' then ''User table''
when sysobjects.xtype = ''UQ'' then ''UNIQUE constraint''
when sysobjects.xtype = ''V'' then ''View''
when sysobjects.xtype = ''X'' then ''Extended stored procedure''
end as [Object Type]
FROM sysobjects
WHERE
sysobjects.type in (''C'',''D'',''F'',''FN'',''P'',''K'',''S'',''TF'',''TR'',''U'',''V'',''X'')
AND sysobjects.category = 0
AND CHARINDEX(''@SEARCHSTRING'',sysobjects.name)>0
AND ((CHARINDEX(''@notcontain'',sysobjects.name)=0 or 
CHARINDEX(''@notcontain'',sysobjects.name)<>0)) 
)a'

    set @textinit=replace(@textinit,'@SEARCHSTRING',@SEARCHSTRING)
    set @textinit=replace(@textinit,'@notcontain',@notcontain)


SELECT name AS dbName,cast(null as varchar(255)) as ObjectName,cast(null as varchar(255)) as ObjectType  
into ##temp1 
from master.dbo.sysdatabases order by name

SELECT * INTO ##temp2 FROM ##temp1 WHERE 1 = 0


declare @sifra VARCHAR(255),@suma int,@brojac int

set @suma=(select count(dbName) from ##temp1) 

DECLARE c_k CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT dbName FROM ##temp1 ORDER BY dbName DESC

OPEN c_k
FETCH NEXT FROM c_K INTO @sifra
SET @brojac = 1
WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0 ) AND (@brojac <= @suma)
BEGIN

    set @text=replace(@textinit,'@sifra',@sifra)

    exec (@text)

    SET @brojac = @brojac +1

    DELETE FROM ##temp1 WHERE dbName = @sifra

       FETCH NEXT FROM c_k INTO @sifra 
END
close c_k
DEALLOCATE c_k

select * from ##temp2
order by dbName,ObjectType
drop table ##temp2
drop table ##temp1
```

Comment: Remember than any other process can read or modify global temp tables (prefixed by ##). You might get some unexpected results or errors if you are unlucky. In an unlikely scenario this can even compromise security.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT NAME AS ObjectName
    ,schema_name(o.schema_id) AS SchemaName, OBJECT_NAME(o.parent_object_id) as TableName
    ,type
    ,o.type_desc
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND o.NAME LIKE '%UniqueID%'
ORDER BY o.NAME
```

Comment: I don't think this is cross database.

Answer (score 1):

mayby one little change from the top answer, because `DB_NAME()` returns always content db of execution. so, for me better like below:

```
sp_MSforeachdb 'select DB_name(db_id(''?'')) as DB, * From ?..sysobjects where xtype in (''U'', ''P'') And name like ''[_]x[_]%'''
```

In my case I was looking for tables their names started with `_x_`

Cheers,
Ondrej

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20132642/3207126) are some arguments to avoid using 'sp_MSforeachdb'

Answer (score 0):

----Option 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    o.name,
    o.xtype
FROM
    syscomments c
    INNER JOIN
        sysobjects o
        ON
            c.id=o.id
WHERE
    c.TEXT LIKE '%TableName%'
order by
    o.name desc,
    o.xtype desc
```

Answer (score 0):

`select db_name(), * From sysobjects where xtype in ('U', 'P') And name = 'OBJECT_name'`

First column will display name of database where object is located at.