# sp_MSforeachdb: only include results from databases with results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm running the below stored procedure `sp_MSforeachdb` with a simple command. My question is how to limit the result to show only the databases that have at least 1 record satisfying the command:

[image: Sample of the result]

Here's my stored procedure:

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; 

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''Tabs''))
BEGIN

SELECT ''?'' as dbname,T.TabName, T.TabPath
FROM Tabs T
WHERE T.TabID IN (

SELECT Distinct TM.TabID
FROM TabModules TM
WHERE mID IN (
  ...
  )

)
ORDER BY T.TabName
END
'
```

Any ideas how I can modify the sp so that it doesn't display the databases that have empty results (see image)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, first, stop using `sp_MSforEachDb`. Oh, the problems (if you want proof, see [here](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior)).

How about:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'', @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @cmd += N'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM '
  + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.tables WHERE name = N''Tabs'')
  SET @sql += N''UNION ALL 
    SELECT ''''' + name + ''''',T.TabName
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.Tabs AS T
    WHERE EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.TabModules AS TM
        WHERE TM.TabID = T.TabID
        AND TM.mID IN -- this should probably be exists too
        ( 
          ...
        )
    )
'''
FROM sys.databases 
  WHERE state = 0 -- assume you only want online databases
  AND database_id > 4; -- assume you don't want system dbs

EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@sql NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @sql OUTPUT;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 10, '') + N' ORDER BY TabName;';   

PRINT @sql; -- this will appear truncated, but trust me, it is not truncated
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

If you really want some unknown, arbitrary number of separate resultsets, the change is simple.

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'', @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @cmd += N'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM '
  + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.tables WHERE name = N''Tabs'')
  SET @sql += N''SELECT ''''' + name + ''''',T.TabName
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.Tabs AS T
    WHERE EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.TabModules AS TM
        WHERE TM.TabID = T.TabID
        AND TM.mID IN -- this should probably be exists too
        ( 
          ...
        )
    )
 ORDER BY T.TabName;
 '';'
FROM sys.databases 
  WHERE state = 0 -- assume you only want online databases
  --AND database_id > 4; -- assume you don't want system dbs

EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@sql NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @sql OUTPUT;

PRINT @sql; -- this will appear truncated, but trust me, it is not truncated
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aaron! I tried your solution, but instead of getting the actual result, I got a SQL query that was truncated at the end (sorry, I'm a total noob when it comes to functions and sp). And when I ran that query separately (and added the truncated portion), the result was all in one table (versus the layout of the result from sp_MSforeachdb: one result table for each DB).. anyway to change that result view?

Comment: The SQL query will be truncated at the end if your query is quite large and/or you have a large number of databases. I can assure that it is not actually getting truncated unless it really has over a billion characters; this is just a sad limitation in the `PRINT` command. I intentionally created it as a `UNION` query because I don't think it's a very common requirement to have an unknown number of resultsets. If that's what you really want, you could always dump the output into a #temp table and then run a cursor against that, processing the rows for each distinct database name...

Comment: hmmm that's weird because it's definitely omitting the last 30 characters or so from the query, and yet the query is waaaay under a billion characters (only 3 databases satisfy the conditions of the query). Also, how can I have that command execute the query directly (without me manually running the generated query)?

Comment: AGAIN, **it is a limitation of the PRINT command**. Make the repeated query shorter and I guarantee you will see it all. And just uncomment the `EXEC` and you will see it gets executed and does not exhibit the error you would expect based on the truncated text that PRINT is showing you. The billion characters was an exaggeration - if you're generating a query here that is a billion characters, you've got other issues.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need another IF to only run the select if data exists.
Here's what i did to test.

On DB1:

```
create table mytesttable(a int)
insert mytesttable values(1)
```

On DB2:

```
create table mytesttable(a int)
```

So you want DB1 to return results, but DB2 not to. you can use the following sql:

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; 

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
             WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''mytesttable''))
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytesttable) BEGIN
    SELECT ''?'' as dbname,T.A
    FROM mytesttable AS T
END
END
'
```

This only returns:
db1, 1