# Select version number and database name from all databases

Tags: sql-server

I want an overview of a certain server's databases and their current version number from our versioning table.

Imagine my databases look like this:

```
master (no version table) 
database1.bhr.databaseVersion
    version: 5
    version: 6
database2.bhr.databaseVersion
    version: 5
someOtherDb (no version table)
```

The query result would look like this:

```
Name        Version
database1   6
database1   5
```

I know I could first query all database names from sys.databases and then construct dynamic queries by enumerating the results.
For the sake of learning, however, I would like to know if it is possible to do this all within a single query batch.

Comment: I hope my example is a bit clear. Don't really know how to express it more comprehensible and concise

Comment: Someone is going to suggest sp_MSforeachdb, so take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131930/sp-msforeachdb-only-include-results-from-databases-with-results).

Comment: You could dynamically construct a single query, but I don't know if that's really what you mean by your question.   if this is an ongoing need, you might consider keeping databaseVersions in a single metadata table.

Comment: @tab alleman: that would make migrating tables from one server to another complicated

Comment: I don't see why it would make it any more complicated than it already is.   If migrating tables affects DB Versions, what does it matter if you update the table IN the database or a table in a meta-database?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQL is the way to go:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select '
declare @delim nvarchar(1) = ''

select  @sql = @sql + @delim + 'DatabasePropertyEX(''' + name + ''', ''version'') [' + name + ']',
        @delim = ','
    from master.sys.databases 

exec(@sql)
```

You could probably use the STUFF function if you don't like the concatenation method, but for this purpose, unless you've got thousands of databases on this server, it'll work just fine.