# Select query from all databases where a table exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am looking for a query where it will bring back results from all databases but only where a table exists.

I have run `EXEC sp_MsForEachDb @command1 = 'select * from ?.dbo.users'` but this brings back a lot of errors and therefore hides the results from the databases that do have these tables

Comment: Could you please post those errors as well, that will help...

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131930/sp-msforeachdb-only-include-results-from-databases-with-results)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can still get to the results tab, even when it errors

Answer (score 1):

```
`EXEC sp_MsForEachDb @command1 = 
' use ?; if exists(select  * from  information_schema.tables where table_`name=''test'' )begin select * from test end'
```

the above statement will hide all errors ,since it checks for existence of table first..

you also can exclude system databases like..

```
EXEC sp_MsForEachDb @command1 = ' use ?;  if db_id()<=4 return  if exists(select * from  information_schema.tables where table_name=''test'' )begin select * from test end'
```