# Select from all tables in all databases with specific name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to query all the tables with specific name in all databases on server.
Databases creates daily by ISA and its names generates by mask *ISALOG_**current_date**_WEB_000*. Each database contains table *WebProxyLog*. Total count of databases is 60.
My goal is to query *WebProxyLog* table in all databases or in databases of specific dates.
Something like foreach loop:

```
foreach($db in $databases)
{
   if($db.Name.Contains("_web"))
    {
     SELECT [ClientUserName],[logTime],[uri],[UrlDestHost],[bytesrecvd],[bytessent],[rule]
     FROM [$db].[dbo].[WebProxyLog]
     WHERE [ClientUserName] like ''%username%''
    }
}
```

Perfect if result of query will be merged in single table or view.
Is there a way to perform that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an undocumented stored procedure called sp_MSForEachDB, However, I would not rush to use undocumented features. This can by done by using dynamic SQL that gets the databases names from `sys.DataBases` system table:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = N''


SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 
'UNION ALL 
     SELECT ['+ name +'] As DBName, [ClientUserName],[logTime],[uri],[UrlDestHost],[bytesrecvd],[bytessent],[rule]
     FROM [' + name + '].[dbo].[WebProxyLog]
     WHERE [ClientUserName] like ''%username%''

'
FROM sys.DataBases 
WHERE name LIKE '%ISALOG%WEB%'

SET @SQL = STUFF(@SQL, 1, 10, '') + ' ORDER BY DBName'

PRINT @SQL

--EXEC(@SQL)
```

Once you've printed the sql and tested it, you can remove the `print` row and un-comment the `exec` row.

Further reading - Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : relying on undocumented behavior](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior) And [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20132642/3094533) to a question on SO about sp_MSForEachDB.

Edit: small correction of SELECT:

```
'UNION ALL 
 SELECT [ClientUserName],[logTime],[uri],[UrlDestHost],[bytesrecvd],[bytessent],[rule]
 FROM [' + name + '].[dbo].[WebProxyLog]
 WHERE [ClientUserName] like ''%username%''
'
```

As result it prints listing of queries to the tables, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I've slightly edited your SELECT and now it works like a charm!

Comment: The `@SQL` variable contains a union query for the tables named `WebProxyLog` in all the databases you mentioned. I've added the database name to the original query but of course you don't have to use it if you don't need it. However, if an answer solved your problem then you should mark it as accepted so that other people will know that the problem is solved.