# Invalid Object Name '' in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I was executing a select statement over `sys.database_permissions` view, but for some  of the databases I am getting the **Invalid Object Name ''** error. Checked with the permissions but still everything seems to be right, not sure what could be causing this issue.

Note: When I ran the `select * from sys.database_permissions` query, I got some result and then the error appeared seems like a invalid data stored in the table.

Could someone please explain what could be the reason for this issue.

I got this error when actually executing the code like below

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachdb '
    SELECT distinct
       p.permission_name ,
       ''?''
FROM   [?].sys.database_permissions p '
```

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34947/can-i-launch-a-stored-procedure-and-immediately-return-without-waiting-for-it-to

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure to understand your requirement. You want to execute a Stored procedure which is really long? You can either execute your stored procedure normally and work in another Document in SSMS. You can also call your stored procedure in a SQL Server Job. In your Object Explorer, go to SQL Server Agent- Job-New Job-add a step and Choose "TSQL script" and type your SQL Code "EXEC...". You can then schedule your job or start it immediately.  You need to be admin to interact with the Agent SQL. Do you have other requirements ?

Comment: Don't use undocumented unofficial unsupported stored procedures like `sp_MSForEachdb` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131930/sp-msforeachdb-only-include-results-from-databases-with-results

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks for letting me know about this but still when I checked with which database is causing the issue and executing the same command prepending with the database name still gives the same error even when I don't use the `sp_MSForEachdb`

Comment: @VaseemAkram - Please edit your question and add the full details of the new test you executed.  The exact query, the exact error message, etc.