# How to avoid showing result-window if there are no results to show?

Tags: sql

I have a script which searches through all the available databases (those I have access to) for a specific text in a procedure.

In my server, there are many databases (in my case about 150 databases), meaning that I get shown the results for all databases eventhough there are no results for most of them (about 90%).

Is there any way to avoid getting these empty result-queries?

Comment: Do you talk about 150 tables in one database or ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sp\_MSforeachdb: only include results from databases with results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131930/sp-msforeachdb-only-include-results-from-databases-with-results)

Comment: No, I am talking about 150 databases with a lot more tables. But I am looking in the stored procedures, not tables anyway.

Comment: I did not manage to solve my problem using your suggestion Venkataraman. I am looking for a general solution, do you have any examples of how this can be written in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to check whether stored procedure contains a text in each database. If there are stored procedures in a database only, you will have resultset.

```sql
CREATE TABLE ##DatabasesContainingSP(dbname sysname, SPName SYSNAME);

EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; 

INSERT INTO ##DatabasesContainingSP
SELECT DISTINCT
       db_name() as dbname, o.name AS Object_Name
  FROM sys.sql_modules m
       INNER JOIN
       sys.objects o
         ON m.object_id = o.object_id
 WHERE m.definition Like ''%ABC%'';
'

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ##DatabasesContainingSP )
begin
SELECT * FROM ##DatabasesContainingSP
end 
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##DatabasesContainingSP' , 'U') IS NOT NULL
   drop TABLE ##DatabasesContainingSP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the quick responses.

I managed to solve it by creating a table and adding insert into this table in the beginning of my generated and concatenated code, which solved the problem since when reading the table in the end, it only shows the inserted results.

With kind regards,
Alexander